# Invalid Authentication Token Once Creating a Content Filter on Microsoft Azure AI Studio

Tags: azure, access-token, azure-ai

I am getting the error "Authentication Token Invalid: Invalid access token" when creating a content filter on Azure AI Studio which ultimately does not allow me to create the content filter. Can someone help me with solving this issue?
I created a content filter the first time and it did not give me any error. Then I deleted it for some reason and when I intended to create it again the mentioned error occurred.

I tried to find any ties between an access token and particularly content filters and ways to resolve them but it did not end up with any success.

Comment: I experience the same issue. We have an enterprise Azure account. Lets hope Microsoft fixes that soon. 

Comment: Add more details on how you are creating it.